# PHP - How to query multiple value of a JSON file?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am building a JSON backend with pure PHP and JS, no MySQKL involved, I would need to know if it's possible to query the same JSON key mode than once.

So, here's my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "id": "WWJaePyv9a",
        "string": "aaa",
        "number": 123.89,
        "aArray": [
            "aa",
            "bb",
            "cc"
        ],
        "bool": true,
        "geocoords": [
            "1.23456",
            "-33.76584"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "vXMv68ze8K",
        "string": "bbb",
        "number": 1.64,
        "aArray": [
            "yyy",
            "ppp"
        ],
        "bool": false,
        "geocoords": [
            ""
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "Imd6oPVYtP",
        "string": "ccc",
        "number": 0,
        "aArray": [
            ""
        ],
        "bool": false,
        "file": "",
        "geocoords": [
            ""
        ]
    }
]
```

Here's my PHP script:

```
<?php 
$className = basename(__DIR__) ;

/* GET variables */
$string = $_GET['string'];
$aArray = $_GET['aArray'];
$number = $_GET['number'];
$bool = $_GET['bool'];
if( $bool == 'true'){ $bool = true; } else if($bool == 'false'){ $bool= false; }


$data = file_get_contents($className. '.json');
$data_array = json_decode($data, true);

$results = array();

foreach ($data_array as $obj) {

    // check value in string
    if(isset($string)){
        if (strpos($obj['string'], $string) !== false) {
            // $results[$obj['id']] = $obj;
            array_push($results, $obj);
        }
    }

    // check element in array
    if(isset($aArray)){
        if (in_array($aArray, $obj['aArray'])) {
            // $results[$obj['id']] = $obj;
            array_push($results, $obj);

        } 
    }

     // check value in number
    if(isset($number)){
        if ($obj['number'] == (float)$number) {
            // $results[$obj['id']] = $obj;
            array_push($results, $obj);
        } 
    }

    // check value in bool
    if(isset($bool)){
        if ($obj['bool'] == $bool) {
            // $results[$obj['id']] = $obj;
            array_push($results, $obj);
        }
    }

}// ./ for

// echo results
echo json_encode(array_values($results), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

And here's my query URL that I paste in Chrome to test that PHP script:

```
https://example.com/query.php?string=aaa&string=bbb
```

Unfortunately, I get only the last array's object of my JSON file, which has "`bbb`" as value for the "`string`" key:

```
[ { "id": "vXMv68ze8K", "string": "bbb", "number": 1.64, "aArray": [ "yyy", "ppp" ], "bool": false, "geocoords": [ "" ] } ]
```

Instead, I would need to get the object that has "`aaa`" as the value of the "`string`" key together with the "`bbb`" one, like this:

```
[ 
   { "id": "WWJaePyv9a", "string": "aaa", "number": 123.89, "aArray": [ "aa", "bb", "cc" ], "bool": true, "geocoords": [ "1.23456", "-33.76584" ] 
   },
   { "id": "vXMv68ze8K", "string": "bbb", "number": 1.64, "aArray": [ "yyy", "ppp" ], "bool": false, "geocoords": [ "" ] 
   } 
]
```

Is this possible? Am I doing something wrong in the code or maybe in the syntax of my query URL?

Comment: Thanks, any example code to help me understand how can I do it? You may post an answer and I'll accept it if it works fine

Comment: PHP _overwrites_ GET/POST parameters of the same name with the last value, unless you use the square bracket “array” syntax. `?string[]=aaa&string[]=bbb` - _now_ `$_GET['string']` will be an array that you can loop over.

Comment: @04FS I used that '?string[]=aaa&string[]=bbb' suffix in my URL but it echoes an empty result: **[]**

Comment: you need to pass your string as array e.g. ? string[]=aa& string[]=bbb and in the PHP you need to change your comparison like : if(isset($string)){
        
        foreach ($string as $k=>$valueString) {
        if (strpos($obj['string'], $valueString) !== false) {
            // $results[$obj['id']] = $obj;
            array_push($results, $obj);
        }
        }
    }

Comment: Your code treats `$string` as if it was an actual string value - which it isn’t, so using it as parameter for `strpos` does not make sense. Again, if you pass an array of data, you should _loop over_ it.

Comment: You will probably need to do this with all of the others, so you will need to change the rest of the code to be able to cope with that - which is why it may sound simple to use JSON, but it isn't.

Comment: If you are only looking for _exact_ matches, then you can also use `in_array`, then you don’t need to loop over the passed values yourself at that point.

Comment: @NigelRen yes, you're right, I'll edit all the other IF statements

Comment: Avoiding those duplicate query-string parameters `string` would make life easier... eg. `strings=aaa,bbb` and then just `$strings = explode($_GET['strings', ','])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the many comments on this question, I could solve the problem by using this code:

```
if(isset($string)){
        foreach ($string as $k=>$value) { 
            if ($obj['string'] == $value) { 
                array_push($results, $obj); 
            }  
        }
    }

    if(isset($number)){
        foreach ($number as $k=>$value) { 
            if ($obj['number'] == $value) { 
                array_push($results, $obj); 
            }  
        }
    }

    if(isset($aArray)){
        foreach ($aArray as $k=>$value) { 
            if (in_array($value, $obj['aArray'])) {
                array_push($results, $obj);
            }  
        }
    }

    if(isset($bool)){
        foreach ($bool as $k=>$value) { 
            if ($obj['bool'] == $value) { 
                array_push($results, $obj);
            }   
        }
    }
```

So, using a URL like this:

```
https://example.com/query.php?string[]=aaa&string[]=ccc&aArray[]=ppp
```

Makes me able to get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: The `[]` annotation reads a bit messy, but does exactly the same as I've suggested.